# Call to a member function hasRole() on null Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Вообще реализовал разбиение ролей следующим образом

В модели User

```
   public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'users_roles', 'user_id', 'role_id');
} 
public function isEmployee()
{
    $roles = $this->roles->toArray();
    return !empty($roles);
}

public function hasRole($check)
{
    return in_array($check, array_pluck($this->roles->toArray(), 'name'));

}

private function getIdInArray($array, $term)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == $term) {
            return $key + 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function makeEmployee($title)
{
    $assigned_roles = array();
    $roles = array_pluck(Role::all()->toArray(), 'name');
    switch ($title) {
        case 'guest':
        {
        $assigned_roles[] = $this->getIdInArray($roles, 'guest');
                $this->roles()->attach($assigned_roles);
         break;
        }
        case 'admin':
        {
        $assigned_roles[] = $this->getIdInArray($roles, 'admin');
                $this->roles()->attach($assigned_roles);
         break;
        }
       case 'moderator':
       {
        $assigned_roles[] = $this->getIdInArray($roles, 'moderator');
                $this->roles()->attach($assigned_roles);
        break;
       }
        default:
        {
        $assigned_roles[] = false;
                $this->roles()->attach($assigned_roles);
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

В роуте вызов

```
Route::any('/monitoring_user', [ 'middleware' => 'role:admin', 'uses' => 
'Admin_controller@monitoring_user']);
```

В Middleware

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next,$role1)      
{

    if ((!$request->user()->hasRole($role1))) {

        return redirect('/success'); 
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Все работает отлично, но потом когда не заходишь на сайт некоторое время страница обновляется и вылетает вот такая ошибка 
Call to a member function hasRole() on null
В этой строке Middleware
if ((!$request->user()->hasRole($role1)))

В чем проблема может кто подскажет и как исправить, заранее всем спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в сессии устарели данные по пользователю. делайте проверку на авторизацию ( я бы сделал такую проверку)

```
if (!Auth::check() || !Auth::user()->hasRole($role1)) {
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь